# Having Trouble Installing Ruby with RVM

Tags: xcode, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby-1.9.2-head on a Mac running OS X 10.6.8 and Xcode 3.2.5.  Whenever I run the command "rvm install ruby-1.9.2-head", I get an error during the "#configuring" part.  The configure.log file says:

./configure --prefix=/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/me/.rvm/usr 
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh tool/config.sub

I've tried completely removing rvm and then re-installing the stable version (1.10.0) according to the instructions on Wayne's RVM homepage to no avail.  Also, I do already have the 1.8.7 version of Ruby (which came with the machine) still installed.

I was successful in installing rvm and Ruby on two other machines that are also running OS X 10.6.8 but they were running Xcode 3.2.6.  Do I perhaps need to upgrade Xcode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`rvm notes`says you just need `Xcode Tools Version 3.2.1 (1613) or later` to install rvm.

I can remember I had to install the latest XCode version since my Lion upgrade to install ruby 1.9.2. Although you running OS X 10.6.8 and not Lion, there should be a new XCode version for you to download.

Comment: I installed Xcode 3.2.6 and even that didn't fix the problem. This is really strange.

Comment: Try getting a higher version of Xcode. And try to install rvm using a package manager like brew. (Even if it fails it might give you better support for debugging the issue, tips like upgrading xcode or such).

Comment: I believe Xcode 3.2.6 is the highest version I can run since I'm on Snow Leopard. Xcode 4+ requires Lion.  Interestingly, I just now installed Ruby 1.9.3-p0 using rvm without a hitch so I guess I'll stick with that version on my MB Air and use 1.9.2 on my other two systems.  I will look into Homebrew as that looks interesting.

Comment: I also think its the latest version of Xcode you can download for Snow Leopard. And Ruby 1.9.3 is the version I would recommend. So congratulations! :)

Comment: But Homebrew and Ruby, I don't know. I also use Homebrew and I like it, but RVM is the best way to go for Ruby. Version management, rubygems for each ruby version, easy to upgrade, no sudo/permission problems, switchable between different Ruby versions and so on. The biggest problem on OSX is Xcode, but there are other solutions for this. For instance if you need another GCC compiler because the Xcode version is too old: [osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)